# How to convert datetime-local value to long value in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a textbox for getting date & time. I want to get that value at jQuery and convert that value into long value..

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="alarm_msg"  class="form-control textbox" />
```

JS

```
var message = $('#alarm_msg').val();
```

and it shown like  2014-04-15T12:59 .. Here i want to remove T from this..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var str='2014-04-15T12:59' // Your Text Box Value Here
    alert(str.replace('T',''));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EwNRJ/1138/)